# Can i put different "Brother" printer laser toner cartridge in different printer model

Tags: laser-printer

I have two laster printers

```
Brother HL 5240 - toner _ TN3145
Brother HL 5340D - toner  TN3250
```

Now those twoo toner cartriges looks exactly same but they both have some plastic hanging out at bottom at different positions so that they don't fit in different model.everything else is same

i want to ask that i break that plastic about "1.5CM" so that it fits in new printer. Will that work

EDIT: This worked very well

Comment: Well, hopefully you asked superusers about the risk, to make an informed decision about it :-]

Comment: I have one year warranty on printer and i have original cartridge saved so in cas eof problem i will return it back. If the problem arises , they won't be able to know why as i have not touched the new printer , only old cartridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to ask that i break that
>   plastic about "1.5CM" so that it fits
>   in new printer.

And if you break the **new** printer in the process you may void the warranty, is it really worth it?

Comment: I am not messing with the new printer. Actually i have to get the new printer beacuse ts duplex printer while old prints only single side.
But the cartridge is full on old printer. i was thinking if can use old cartridge.

Comment: @Mirage - i know what you were thinking :) however, there is always the risk of damaging the printer with an incompatible toner cartridge and i will not encourage you to try it. Anyway, it is your printer and you're responsible for it, the call is yours.

Comment: Is duplex printing the function of printer or it has anything to do with drum or toner cartridge. Because the looks of printer is exactly same. I think for a big company who produces millions of units. i don't thnink they can make slight differtent functions internally otherise they have to spend lot more money just to make them different

Comment: @Mirage - Duplex printing is a feature that allows printing of a sheet of paper on both sides.

Comment: no no , i mean to say that this feature is done by printer internal hrdware or by the  drum/Cartridge

Comment: @Mirage - well, it is done by the printer alright, but then, it can't be done without drum or cartridge :)

Comment: I tried that and broke the plastic and it worked perfectly. wow

Comment: @Mirage very well :)

Answer (score 2):

Because the two laser toners have that specific bit of plastic preventing their use in other models, there is likely a difference between them.  They may, for example, carry different ink or expel ink in a different manner.  They may simply not interface the same way with the printer.

If you have nothing else to use the cartridge that you are thinking about breaking for, then I would say to go ahead and try it, but know that there is at least a 50/50 chance it will not work.